# adding CSS on hover with Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, hover

On hover I want to change background from a div. therefore I used Jquery. But somehow it doesn't work, not in an empty file, not in an HTML file and not in a file with different Jquery codes.

```js
$('#b').hover(function() {
  $('#a').css({
    'background': '#ccc'
  });
}, function() {
  $('#a').css({
    'background': 'initial'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine as you can see from the snippet I edited in to your question. Check the console for errors. It's likely to be a configuration error, such as not including jquery.js, incorrect path, or missing document.ready handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Your code in working condition please place your jquery code after jquery library  
`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="a">Div A</div>
       <div id="b">Div B</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
$('#b').hover(function() {
  $('#a').css({
    'background': '#ccc'
  });
}, function() {
  $('#a').css({
    'background': 'initial'
  });
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>`
```